# How can I create a function that allows me to reverse the order of the columns of a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have created the following matrix:

```
A6=np.matrix(([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]))
```

and I did the respective exercise of inverting the columns, but now I want to do it through a function

```
B = A6[:,::-1]
```

Comment: `np.fliplr` does exactly this.  Read its code.

Comment: According to numpy.org, use of matrix is discouraged. Use regular arrays instead. Writing a function to rearrange the rows is then trivial albeit unnecessary. Having said that, @hpaulj's answer is entirely correct and works for both matrix and array types